# SQL ERROR - Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table that contain a Year column and a Month column. Year is an INT and month is a VARCHAR as in 'January'. I am creating a report into which the user should be able to simply put a To and From date. This is my stored procedure.

**SQL**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Servicing].[ManualAdjustments]

@dateFrom INT,
@dateTo VARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
    WHERE RefYear BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,YEAR(@dateFrom)) AND CONVERT(DATE,YEAR(@dateTo))
    AND RefMonth BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,MONTH(@dateFrom)) AND CONVERT(DATE,MONTH(@dateTo))
END
```

When I run it, it comes back with 'Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.' I'm not exactly sure what I've done wrong in the syntax.
I've looked at other examples on SO but the answers are based solely on the askers problem so I'm finding it difficult gettting to how to solve my problem.

Any ideas?

**EDIT - What I've tried**

**1**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Servicing].[ManualAdjustments]

@dateFrom DATE,
@dateTo DATE

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
    WHERE RefYear BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,YEAR(@dateFrom),0) AND @dateTo
    AND RefMonth BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,MONTH(@dateFrom),0) AND @dateTo
END
--ERROR -> 'Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.'
```

Comment: So you want date parameters as int and varchar? Why not a date datatype?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio to create the report so ideally I would like the from and to to be in date format so the user can simply choose the dates using a calendar. I prefer to convert to date format. When I put the variables as DATE it doesn't run and I get this 'Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int'.

Comment: I agree with @HoneyBadger `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` should be the datatype `date`, they ***are*** dates after all.

Comment: This SQL is not making sense, year / month functions return a year / month from a date as an int value - you can't convert that arbitrarily to a date.

Comment: Thats not a good practice either, how would you expect if `year = 2018 and month = March` to reconcile, send them either both integers or datetimes

Comment: Is it possible to get an example? I'm very new to SQL.

Comment: Not sure what's worst - date as int or date as varchar. Both are terrible options.

Comment: Year is an integer for some reason and Month is a string because we store months as 'January'. I didn't create the table but I have to find a way without making changes to the table I suppose.

Comment: @NikosV if user enters `year = 2017 and month = August`, do u expect results to be returned from `01-01-2017 till 31-08-2017` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution to this problem is to change the table's structure, to create a `RefDate` column of type `Date`. Assuming you can't do that, you are going to have to do some tricky stuff in your stored procedure.

In the stored procedure, however, you should take the `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` parameters as type `Date`.

Then you can use a common table expression to map the names of the months to month numbers (because when sorted as strings, `February` comes before `January`), and then you can use `between...and`.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Servicing].[ManualAdjustments]

@dateFrom date,
@dateTo date

AS
BEGIN

    With CTEMonths AS
    (
        SELECT Id, Name
        FROM (VALUES 
              (1, 'January'),
              (2, 'February'),
              (3, 'March'),
              (4, 'April'),
              (5, 'May'),
              (6, 'June'),
              (7, 'July'),
              (8, 'August'),
              (9, 'September'),
              (10, 'October'),
              (11, 'November'),
              (12, 'December')
             ) v(Id, Name)
    )

    SELECT  *
    FROM MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
    JOIN CTEMonths c ON RefMonth = c.Name
    WHERE RefYear BETWEEN YEAR(@dateFrom) AND YEAR(@dateTo)
    AND c.Id BETWEEN MONTH(@dateFrom) AND MONTH(@dateTo)

END
```

Comment: So that I understand. You've basically created a temporary table with values and names, joined the temp table onto the common RefMonth column and did the comparisons. Is that correct?

Comment: A [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is not exactly a temporary table but you can think about it as such, so yes.

Comment: OK. I'll look up on CTE's see what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2000;
DECLARE @MONTH VARCHAR(50) = 'february';

WITH aDATE
AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(year, @YEAR - 1800,'18000101') X

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, aDATE.X)
    FROM aDATE
    WHERE YEAR(DATEADD(month, 1, aDATE.X)) % 10 = @YEAr % 10
    )
    ,RANGE
AS (
    SELECT x MonthStart
        ,dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, 1, x)) MonthEnd
    FROM aDATE
    WHERE DATENAME(month, x) = @MONTH
    )
SELECT *
FROM RANGE
```